# NETStandard.Library being referenced in .NET Standard 2.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

I am not sure how my Visual Studio 2019 got into this state but when I try to open a project that targets .NET Standard 2.0 it automatically adds a dependency for NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 instead of 2.0.3 and this is preventing me from compiling solutions at my work.

I have tried to manually update the NuGet for this project but it is saying that it is blocked by the project (see below image).

Also, this issue happens to any project that I target .NET Standard 2.0, including a new class library project with no other references/dependencies!

I have tried manually installing .NET Core 2.0 SDK (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-2.1.202-windows-x64-installer) but it didn't make any difference.  The issue does not happen for anyone else on my team.

I would appreciate any suggestions and I am stuck!!

[image]

[image]

Below is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>NetStandard2._0</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Right-click the project (bold node) and select "Edit Project File".  That's what you got to show us to get help.

Comment: Will do when I log into work tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: create a new project and use different name for your solution, maybe the name causes the issue

Comment: @magicandre1981 the issue persists with a different name for solution.  The new name is "netstandard"

Comment: I had to do a [repair install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to fix Xamarin issues, maybe this also helps you

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the suggestion and I finished repairing my Visual Studio 2019 install and it didn't make any difference.  I even tried updating to the latest version.

Comment: do you have a global.json that points to old .Net Core 1.1 SDK? post output of **dotnet --info** I just tested it and it adds 2.0.3 to my new lib .

Comment: I don't have a global.json in my project.

Comment: [report it to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/feedback-options?view=vs-2019#report-a-problem)